# In Amaranto, is Troy a girl or boy?

Tags: amaranto

In the Visual Novel [Amaranto](http://vndb.org/v1987), one of the members of Triad is Troy. I'm playing the English patch of it now, and they refer to Troy as a "she". When they say Troy's name, it does sound exactly like they've translated it. However I'm confused about whether this is a translation error or not.

**Points that indicate that Troy could be a girl**

- All characters that are in the story or mentioned but two are girls (the two guys being a nameless vagrant that Mio was about to kill and the strawberry-loving owner of the cafe Yuuki's group hangs out in).
- It's noted that Queen hates men, even going so far as to kill most of them off when she takes over a Sect, and since the Triad are like her elite guard, she would have nothing but girls in it.
- The twins joke about how Troy only has eyes for "Senpai" which refers to Ria, since all the relationships shown/possible are Shoujo Ai (female × female). So, this would be the same with Troy and Ria.

**Points that indicate that Troy could be a boy**

- Troy is a guy's name at least in English (in Japanese, it's pronounced as *to-ro-i* / トロイ) however in the game it seemed to be pronounced as *to-ro-i-a* / トロイア so the English name may be a mistranslation.
- Troy's appearance:

[image: Troy by himself]
[image: Triad]

- Troy sounds like a boy (but that could mean little)

So I am wondering, is Troy a girl, or is Troy actually a boy (and the translation is wrong)?

Comment: I know nothing about this VN, but [VNDB claims](http://vndb.org/c11438) that Troy is female and transgender.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that edit. I didn't quite catch what you meant there.

Comment: wow, i dont know this vn... and its english. thanks @Memor-X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Troy's profile from the official site's character introduction.](http://www.trifolium-garden.net/amaranto/chara/11.html)

[image: Troy's profile]

Although Troy's appearance is like a boy, Troy is a **she**. From the last paragraph of Troy's description:

> 口数が少なく、常に行動を共にする双子も
> **彼女**のことはよく知らない。
>
> Does not talk much, and even the twins whom Troy usually act together with
> do not know much about **her**.

While [VNDB](http://vndb.org/c11438) claims that she is also a transgender, I don't have any proof to support or counter it. However, from the sample dialog on the image,

> 「そんなの、**ボク**には関係ない。
> 　　君たちの好きにすればいいだろ」

she refers to herself as **ボク (*boku*)** which defines her personality as a [*bokukko*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Bokukko) (**Warning: TV Tropes link**)

> A Bokukko is, literally, a girl who uses the first-person Japanese Pronoun *boku*, primarily used by boys and young men. [...]
>
> Most bokukko are tomboys, but not all; sometimes it just indicates that the user is a Plucky Girl or unaware of social norms. [...] Although none of this has to be reflected in her appearance, bokukko are usually either flat-chested or extremely well-endowed.
>
> This speech pattern can also be used to keep a character's gender obscured—is she a boyish girl, or a girlish boy?

Last but not least, Kisaki Kotori ― the voice-actor herself ― [listed her role on her official site](http://littleconcert0.web.fc2.com/work.htm) as female for Troy.

> トロイア役 (Troy)　♀

---

Regarding the name トロイア (*toroia*) as Troy, most possibly it refers to [Troy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy), a city used as the setting of the famous Trojan War. [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA%E3%82%B9) lists トロイア (*toroia*), トロイ (*toroi*) and トロイアー (*toroia-*) as the possible pronunciations.